# Why is clang dereferencing a parameter on every use?

Tags: c++, windows, clang++

I have been performing performance optimisations on some code at work, and stumbled upon some strange behaviour, which I've boiled down to the simple snippet of C++ code below:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void Foo(uint8_t*& out)
{
    out[0] = 1;
    out[1] = 2;
    out[2] = 3;
    out[3] = 4;
}
```

I then compile it with clang (on Windows) with the following: `clang -S -O3 -masm=intel test.cpp`. This results in the following assembly:

```
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rcx]
        mov     byte ptr [rax], 1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rcx]
        mov     byte ptr [rax + 1], 2
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rcx]
        mov     byte ptr [rax + 2], 3
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rcx]
        mov     byte ptr [rax + 3], 4
        ret
```

Why has clang generated code that repeatedly dereferences the `out` parameter into the `rax` register? This seems like a really obvious optimization that it is deliberately not making, so the question is why?

Interestingly, I've tried changing `uint8_t` to `uint16_t` and this much better machine code is generated as a result:

```
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rcx]
        movabs  rcx, 1125912791875585
        mov     qword ptr [rax], rcx
        ret
```

Comment: Why do you pass the pointer by reference? That makes no sense, as you don't modify the pointer and it will only add an extra level of indirection. What happens if you don't pass the pointer by reference? On [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vo3jEe) it seems to make a *lot* of difference.

Comment: Your "much better" code also fetches the address every time. You just don't notice it because it only happens once.

Comment: I pass the pointer by reference because in my real code, I do modify it. It's not modified in the code in the question because I've boiled it down to the simplest possible that demonstrates the observed behaviour.

Comment: Example in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/d3E3Ex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler cannot do such optimization simply due to strict aliasing as `uint8_t` is always* defined as `unsigned char`. Therefore it can point to any memory location, which means it can also point to itself and because you pass it as a reference, the writes can have side-effects inside the function.

Here is obscure, yet correct, usage dependent on non-cached reads:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <stdint.h>
void Foo(uint8_t*& out)
{
    uint8_t local;
    // CANNOT be used as a cached value further down in the code.
    uint8_t* tmp = out;
    // Recover the stored pointer.
    uint8_t **orig =reinterpret_cast<uint8_t**>(out);
    // CHANGES `out` itself;
    *orig=&local;

    **orig=5;
    assert(local==5);
    // IS NOT EQUAL even though we did not touch `out` at all;
    assert(tmp!=out);
    assert(out==&local);
    assert(*out==5);
}

int main(){
   // True type of the stored ptr is uint8_t**
   uint8_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&ptr);

   Foo(ptr);
}
```

This also explains why `uint16_t` generates "optimized" code because `uin16_t` can never* be `(unsigned) char` so the compiler is free to assume that it does not alias other pointer types such as itself.

*Maybe some irrelevant obscure platforms with differently-sized bytes. That is beside the point.